# Foreach code not working

Tags: php, foreach, if-statement

I cannot figure out whats wrong with this segment of code:

```
}else{
$error_message = '<span class="error">';
foreach($error as $key => $values){
    $error_message.= "$values<br />";
}
$error_message.="</span><br /><br />";
}
```

I get the error:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in FILE DIRECTORY on line 45

Line 45 is the `foreach($error...` line

**Solved**: My issue was I messed up the placement of curly brackets which in turn messed up the array

Comment: Show the code where `$error` is generated please.

Comment: `$error` mustn't be an array (or other iterable type)

Comment: Your `$error` variable is obviously not an array as it should be. Put `var_dump($error);` in front of that foreach and look for the result.

Comment: Errors messages are your best friend, you got the answer to your question before you even asked, but just ignored it, sadly...

Comment: @Matt Don't put [Solved] in the title of your question. Either select an answer below or add one yourself explaining how you solved the problem.

Answer (score 5):

The error message said that `$error` is not an array. You could check it by `var_dump($error);` before the loop to check what it is.

Comment: I do have $error set to an array earlier in my code. But it responds as null, any advice for that?

Comment: @Matt The error message won't lie. What do you have by `var_dump` it ?

Comment: Could it be that the code you have shown is inside a function and `$error` is defined outside of it?

Answer (score 0):

If `$error` is sometimes null then the following should suffice:

```
}else{
    if(!empty($error)){ // only attempt to build error messages if there are errors
        $error_message = '<span class="error">';
        foreach($error as $key => $values){
            $error_message.= "$values<br />";
        }
        $error_message.="</span><br /><br />";
    }
}
```